# Getting duplicate values as a list in oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have following table in a oracle db

```
id       group
100       1
101       2
102       2
103       1
104       1
```

I need to get the ids as a comma separated list grouped by group as below.

```
group       ids
  1       100,103,104
  2       101,102
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle 11g introduced the [`listagg`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions089.htm) function:

```
SELECT   "group", LISTAGG(id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) AS ids
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY "group"
```

Note: `group` is a reserved word in SQL, hence the quotes to protect it as a column name. If your real table has a different name, you won't need them.